# Duplicate mysql datadir on Windows

Tags: windows, mysql

I have a development server running Mysql 5.1 (together with other services). During an urgent cleanup I found, using SequoiaView, two identical mysql data folders.

- C:\ProgramData\MySQL\etc.... is the directory referenced by my.ini
- C:\Users\All Users\MySQL contains the same data

I am concerned that ibdata1, still huge, occupies double the space.

I have checked that ibdata1 under C:\Users is not only identical in size, but has the same access time as the one under C:\ProgramData.

I have then tried to rename both folders to see which was not "in use" by Windows. Both were used.

I suspected someone created a dual instance of mysqld (unfortunately I am not the only administrator of this machine, but more unfortunately I am not **the** admin responsible for that), but I found no evidence.

### The question is

Why in the world should MySQL use twice the space? How can I safely remove a copy without breaking the entire thing?

Comment: Its possible that it is a hardlink or junction - only one file, but multiple links to it; only takes up the space once

Comment: Could be. How do I find out if it's just a hardlink/junction and possibly delete one of them?

Comment: Honestly its not something im very familiar with, but had come across before. I believe there is good information here on SE, and on MS' s Technet